# codeigniter array json and flashdata

Tags: php, arrays, json, codeigniter, session-variables

I am using *Codeigniter 3* and getting data from an API.  The API returns the below after I pass the origin json data through,  `$myArray = json_decode($theBody, true);`

```
array(2) {
  ["status"]=>
  string(7) "failure"
  ["message"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["entry_name"]=>
    string(61) "The entry_name field must be at least 8 characters in length."
    ["entry_body"]=>
    string(61) "The entry_body field must be at least 8 characters in length."
  }
}
```

I now want to pass that error message via flashdata to my view which I do as follows:

```
// VIEW FILENAME: new.php
$this->session->set_flashdata('message', $myArray);
```

In my view, when I run this:

```
       echo "<pre>";
        echo var_dump($this->session->flashdata('message'));
        echo "</pre>";
```

I get the expected output (same as above):

```
   array(2) {
  ["status"]=>
  string(7) "failure"
  ["message"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["entry_name"]=>
    string(61) "The entry_name field must be at least 8 characters in length."
    ["entry_body"]=>
    string(61) "The entry_body field must be at least 8 characters in length."
  }
}
```

However, how can I iterate through the array?

How can I refer to the contents of `["status"]` and `["message"]`

Any pointers appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Take the values in the variable and navigate to the array values as follows:

```
$flashData = $this->session->flashdata('message');
$status = $flashData['status'];
$message = $flashData['message'];
$entry_name = $flashData['message']['entry_name'];
$entry_body = $flashData['message']['entry_body'];
```

> Check the array How its coming through, If Zero indexed add `[0]` front of the array pointer. (Ex: `$flashData[0]['entry_name']`)

Answer (score 2):

you can access flashdata fields by its key since its an associative array.

```
$flashdata = $this->session->flashdata('message');
$status = $flashdata['status'];
```

As `message` is an array, iterate through array to fetch its value.

```
foreach($flashdata['message'] as $key => $value){
     echo $value;
}
```

Comment: Add some useful explanation to your answer

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. I have edited my answer.